# The number of primes in an interval

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the smallest known $c$ so that for any $n\geq 2$ there are at least $n/\log_2{n}$ primes between $n$ and $cn$ (inclusive)?

The [prime number theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) seems to give an asymptotic result so I am not sure how to get a particular constant from it.

Comment: The PNT says that asymptotically, $1+\log 2$ is enough for large $n$. Now look at small $n$. For $n = 6$, we find $c \geqslant \frac{13}{6}$. That _might_ do.

Comment: Answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206708/smallest-c-so-that-there-are-at-least-n-log-2n-primes-between-n-and-cn

Answer (score 1):

[Terry Tao's notes](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/254a-notes-6-large-values-of-dirichlet-polynomials-zero-density-estimates-and-primes-in-short-intervals/) give a version of the prime number theorem in short intervals:
$$
\sum_{x\le n\le x+y}\Lambda(n)\sim y
$$
for $x\to\infty$ and $x^{3/4+\varepsilon}\le y\le x.$ So with $y=x\log 2$
$$
\sum_{x\le n\le x+y}\Lambda(n)\sim y
$$
and thus
$$
\pi(x+y)-\pi(x)\sim y/\log(x+y)+O(\sqrt{x+y})\sim x\log 2/\log x
$$
and so 'all' that is required is finite checking. As Daniel Fischer suggests in a comment, 13/6 may suffice.

Comment: Would you mind being explicit about what finite checking is needed?

Comment: @Lembik: I can't -- we don't have an effective version of the Prime Number Theorem afaik.